# Unityのシステムフォントサイズを拡大する方法はありますか？

Tags: unity3d

unityで作成するプロジェクトで使用するフォントではなく、ファイルや編集、インスペクター等のunity自体のフォントサイズは変更可能ですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながらUnity自体の機能ではEditor内の文字のサイズを変更することができません。

OSのシステムフォントのサイズを変更することで、擬似的にUnity内の文字の大きさを変えることはできるようです。